# Best practice for JSF 2 dynamic Menu handling?

Tags: java, jsf, menu, java-ee-6, cdi

i am looking for a best practice handling a simple menu with JSF and CDI.

I would like to have a top menu with dynamic entries. Something like (from the main template):

```
            <ul>
                <c:forEach var="menuItem" items="#{navigationBean.topMenuItems}">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="#{navigationBean.isSelectedTop(menuItem.name)}">
                            <li class="current_page_item"><h:outputLink value="#{menuItem.url}"><h:outputText value="#{menuItem.name}" /></h:outputLink></li>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <li><h:outputLink value="#{menuItem.url}"><h:outputText value="#{menuItem.name}" /></h:outputLink></li>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </c:forEach>
            </ul>
```

NavigationBean (Sessionscoped, and holding a list of NavigationItems) and NavigationItem are only beans. Then opening another view I set the current view ID as selected within the navigatiobean:

```
@PostConstruct 
private void init (){

    navigation.setSelectedTopMenu(getViewId());
}
```

The problem is, it is too late. The page is already rendered and no view id is selected.

Is this approach not good at all? Are there any best practices? Searching for JSF menu and JSF navigation leads to other problems, so I couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I strongly advise against using JSP-taglibs (c:) in JSF 2.0 / Facelets. Those tags are **not** part of the JSF-component tree - while some tags might work on the first page render, you'll run into a lot of trouble as soon as you have the page refreshed or (partially) rerendered. This might also be your problem in the described case.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use component binding (for example to h:panelGroup) and whole menu generate in binding method.

JSF page:

```
<h:panelGroup binding="navigationBean.navigationMenu" />
```

Bean:

```
public HtmlPanelGroup getNavigationMenu() {
     HtmlPanelGroup menu = new HtmlPanelGroup();
     menu.setId("menu");
     HtmlOutputLink link = new HtmlOutputLink();
     // ... other components etc.
     menu.getChildren().add(link);
}
```